# Why does font change size when I shrink QTableWidget column

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have a simple Python application with a PyQt QTableWidget with multiple columns and rows.  If the user resizes a column to a size that is just smaller than the cell can hold.. the font of the cell will shrink by about 1 point in size (see animated GIF below).  I have fiddled with almost every QTableWidget setting in QtDesigner.  I would like the font size to remain consistent regardless.

What is causing this and how can I prevent it?

[image: QTableWiget Cell]

Update:

In my `__main__` section, I create a stylesheet for buttons.

I apply this style sheet using setStyleSheet.

If I comment-out setStyleSheet, the problem goes away.

Adding `QTableWidget{font: 9pt "Segoe UI";}` also fixes, but I'd rather not do that.

Why is this stylesheet causing this?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    stylesheet = """
    QPushButton:hover, QComboBox:hover
    {
        background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #cbc9c5, stop: 1 #b9b7b5);
        border: 2px solid #78879b;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    """    

    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)       

    myapp = MyProgram()      # instantiate the main window
    myapp.show()             # show the main window

    rc = app.exec_()

    myapp.close()

    sys.exit(rc)   # exit with the same return code of Qt application
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: My QTableWidget shows PyQt4.QtGui.QCommonStyle

Comment: @panofish no, what is the output of the command that I have indicated: `print(QtGui.QApplication.style().objectName())`?

Comment: Sorry @eyllanesc    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objectName'

Comment: @panofish You have to execute it after `app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)`

Comment: @eyllanesc See code above... after QApplication it says "windowsvista", after setStyle it says plastique, after setStyleSheet it says nothing.